# Firebase get value from one field when searching for different field

Tags: firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

As of right now I am using firebase to get a user in a "users" collection like this:

```
val query: Query = usersCol.whereEqualTo(USERNAME_KEY, usernameInput)
```

**USERNAME_KEY** is a string "username" which is the same as in the database

**usernameInput** is the username of the user I'm getting from the database

(The primary key is an id that I can't search for)
Is it possible to get the value this primary key? or other fields in the same "level" as username, like 'name' or 'password'

I'm imagining something like:

```
   query.get("id")
```

but that doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

You will need to *execute* the query before you can get results from it. As shown in the Firebase documentation you can [execute a query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) like this:

```
query
    .get()
    .addOnSuccessListener { documents ->
        for (document in documents) {
            Log.d(TAG, "${document.id} => ${document.data}")
        }
    }
    .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
        Log.w(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", exception)
    }
```

Within that loop, you can get a specific field from the `document` with:

```
document.get("name")
```